# Sharing Cookie between multiple ASP.NET Core applications

Tags: cookies, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-identity

I have a question regarding sharing of cookies between multiple ASP.NET Core applications and Entity Framework. A brief overview of the architecture. 
One of the applications, lets call it Project A, is responsible for providing the Views required to the user. The other application, Project B, is a REST API that contains the main business logic along with offering CRUD operations on the SQL-Server database. Project A only displays the data it receives from Project B and posts data to Project B, which is eventually inserted into the database. I'm using the Cookie based Authentication.

When the user clicks the submit button on the login page, the username is sent to Project B. The appropriate controller action method in Project B checks to see if the user exists in the database. If the user exists, then all of the user's Claims are stored in a ClaimsPrincipal, which is then used to sign in the user using the AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync method. The calling of this method would create the authentication cookie as per my understanding. In Project A, the cookie returned by Project B is decrypted and is used to call the AuthenticationHttpContextExtensions.SignInAsync in the Project A.

**My question is, could I avoid persisting the keys to the Filesystem? 
If yes, how do I decrypt the cookie in the application that hasn't created it?**

Thanks in Advance